List of Types of a certain type, enforced at compile time?
Let's say I have a List<Type> object:
List<Type> interestingTypes = (...);

List here is not important to my question; it's just for the sake of example. The important thing is <Type>.
But I want to enforce that all of the Types in the List implement a certain interface. Obviously I could do this at runtime, via something like:
var interestingInterfaceType = typeof(IInterestingInterface);
foreach (var type in interestingTypes)
{
   if (!interestingInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
   {
      throw new BoringException("That's not interesting!");
   }
}

That's fine, insofar as it goes, but is there a way to enforce it at compile time instead? Perhaps something akin to the where clause used in defining generics?

Is there a reason why you can not directly use the interface-type? List<IMyInterest> typesOfInterest = [ a, b, c, ... ]: when a, b, c... implement IMyInterest

@LittleBit, yes, I have a reason for specifically wanting a list of types rather than a list of objects of that type.

What does enforcing it at compile time get you? How do you plan to use those type objects?

This all really sounds like an XY problem to me. I can't think of a valid reason you would want to do this.

No - there is no generic constraint that enforces the values of objects, and since Type objects do not have an inheritance paradigm (meaning the object representing the Parent type and the type object representing the Child type are completely orthogonal), there is not a constraint that would enforce it at compile time.
But even if it were possible, it's not clear how that helps you. Type objects are typically only useful in reflection, which is all done at runtime.
